# How to create endpoint to post data and the response is nested array in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8

I'm a beginner in Laravel and I would like to make API with the response like this

```
elements: [
        {
          title:
            "Please indicate if you agree or disagree with the following statements",
          question: [
            {
              value: "affordable",
              text: "Product is affordable",
            },
            {
              value: "does what it claims",
              text: "Product does what it claims",
            },
            {
              value: "better then others",
              text: "Product is better than other products on the market",
            },
            {
              value: "easy to use",
              text: "Product is easy to use",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
```

here's code in my migration database :

```
Schema::create('question_surveys', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('question_survey_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->json('question');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and in my controller, for store the data that I have created, I tried this

```
$validation = $request->validation([
            'title' => 'required|string',
            'question' => 'required|json',
            
        ]);

        try {
            $response = QuestionSurvey::create($validation);
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Survey Question Successfully Created',
                'data' => $response,
                'code' => 200
            ], 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Something wrong, content was not created successfully',
                'errors' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
```

I tried to post data in postman, the code return 200 but not successfully created. I'm confused what should I do and what the exactly keyword I should search on google to solve this problem. I'm very thankful if you can help me to solve this problem..

Comment: Why are you doing `$response = QuestionSurvey::create($validation);`? Try  this, `$response = QuestionSurvey::create($request->all());`

Comment: i have tried it, but still face the same error @SachinBahukhandi

Comment: does it give any errors?

Comment: no, there isn't error message @NipunTharuksha

Answer (score 0):

instead of these code you can create a table `questions` and relate it with `question_surveys`, One To Many Relationships, like:

1. first create table `questions` and set `value` and `text` as columns, then just add a `foreign key` to `question_surveys` tabel like: `$table->foreignId('question_survey_id');` in the migration.
2. now you have to ways. 1- create spread CRUD for `questions` or in store `question_surveys` send all questions in an array, after store `question_surveys` store questions with `foreign key`, `question_survey_id`.
3. in the `question_surveys` model write:

   ```
   public function question()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
   }
   ```

and in Question model write:

```
public function question_surveys()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(QuestionSurvey::class);
}
```

now when you find QuestionSurvey:

```
$question_survey = QuestionSurvey:://your query;
$question_survey->question; // get all questions related to this `question_surveys`
```

not: if `$question_survey` is array, put `$question_survey->question` in resource.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but is it okay if i know more about what should i write in my controller 'store' function to create the data?

Comment: i'm so sorry i didn't get it about this statement "after store question_surveys store questions with foreign key, question_survey_id."

Comment: you can replace store code with this:
            $subject = QuestionSurvey::create($request->except('question'));
            if($request->filled('question')) $subject->question = $request->question;
            $subject->save();

Comment: One to Many relationship see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rb2Tf8zByRU

Comment: thank you in advance, but in question controller what should i do? i'm so sorry to ask you everything bcs i'm really a beginner in laravel..

Comment: is it true if i write this in my store function Question Controller?
            $response = Question::create($validasi);
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Survey Question Successfully Created',
                'data' => $response,
                'code' => 200
            ]);

Comment: Yes, it is true

Comment: i have tried it, but there is an error : Add [text] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\QuestionSurvey]. is there any mistakes that i made?

Comment:  go to your model and write: protected $fillable = ['colName1', 'colName2']. instead colName put your column table names.

Comment: in question_surveys what column should i add? bcs i only add text and value column in questions migrations.. should i add text and value again in questions?

Comment: any column names that user can insert into them.

Comment: i tried to add question column in question_surveys migrations and i also added $fillable = ['title'] but it's still error with the message : General error: 1364 Field 'question' doesn't have a default value ..

Comment: also add question to $fillable

Comment: try this json in the post man:
{
  "question": [
    {
      "values": "dsfdsf",
      "text": "vvfddf"
    },
    {
      "values": "dsfdsf",
      "text": "vvfddf"
    },
    {
      "values": "dsfdsf",
      "text": "vvfddf"
    },
    {
      "values": "dsfdsf",
      "text": "vvfddf"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: still the same error, i'm so sorry..

Comment: try see YouTube course for Laravel